# pinescript : fill 2 lines background with color

Tags: line, fill, pine-script

i desire to fill the space between two lines with color like this :

```
line.set_x2(lndn_line_high_D1, bar_index)
line.set_x2(lndn_line_low_D1 , bar_index)
fill(lndn_line_low_D1, lndn_line_low_D1, color=lndn_fill_clr_D1)
```

But it doesn't work.
I have tried couples other different tests with no success.

Can someone help me please.
Regards.

Comment: This is impossible now

Comment: ✔ ok. thank you.

Comment: Has to be a [hline](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_hline)